# Why are $f$ and its inverse $f^{-1}$ symmetric with respect to the line $y=x$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:D\longrightarrow B$ and $f^{-1}:B\longrightarrow \mathbb D$ it's inverse where $B,D\subset \mathbb R$. Why are they symmetric refer to the line $y=x$ ? How, in general can we write such a symmetry mathematicaly ? For example, if they are symetric refer to the line $x=h$, then it mean that $f(h-x)=f(h+x)$. How would it look for an axe of symmetry of the form $y=ax+b$ ?

Comment: Well to construct an inverse function from the original function, we make the transformation $(x,y)\rightarrow(y,x)$ which results in the functions being 'mirror images' of each-other about the line $y=x$

Answer (score 2):

I think this video does a good job explaining this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2FBrz8WcZE

In short, we can think about inverse functions as swapping x and y coordinates of points on a graph. If we think about where to put the mirror to achieve this, we would want it where the x and y coordinates are equal, i.e. on the line y=x.